# Get the Click event on setOnTouchListener

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-custom-view, android-scrollview

I am working in an android application and I want to get the click event in  setOnTouchListener of a textview inside a custom Listview. When I returns true from the setOnTouchListener I get the click event correctly but the scroll of the ListView will not work at that part of the textview because I have already another click event in that ListView and I have already Overridden ListView setOnTouchListener.

ListView setOnTouchListener

convertView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if (IsTablet) {
            if (mDetailList.size() > 3)
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        } else {
            if (mDetailList.size() > 2)
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        }
        return false;

    }
});
```

TextView setOnTouchListener

```
private float mDownX;
private float mDownY;
private final float SCROLL_THRESHOLD = 10;
private boolean isOnClick;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    switch (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mDownX = ev.getX();
            mDownY = ev.getY();
            isOnClick = true;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (isOnClick) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onClick ");
                //TODO onClick code
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (isOnClick && (Math.abs(mDownX - ev.getX()) > SCROLL_THRESHOLD || Math.abs(mDownY - ev.getY()) > SCROLL_THRESHOLD)) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "movement detected");
                isOnClick = false;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Is there any way I can get the click event by returning false from TextView setOnTouchListener or please suggest me a another solution to this problem.

Comment: Use `setOnClickListener` on text view. `ScrollView` allows clicks on its contents. To modify events passing through Views, override `onInterceptTouchEvent` of `ScrollView`.

Comment: @S.D. I have used it on the textview...

Comment: If I'm following you, I think you'll need to extend `ListView` and put some logic on the `onInterceptTouchEvent()` to differentiate between up/down swipes, which go to the `ListView`, versus simple touches, which go to the `TextViews`. [This page][1] show how to test for up/down swipes using the `MotionEvent`, which you get as part of the `onInterceptTouchEvent()` method.


  [1]: http://codetheory.in/android-ontouchevent-ontouchlistener-motionevent-to-detect-common-gestures/

Comment: @JASONGPETERSON Great.. Your solution works !!!!

Comment: Glad to hear it, man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for my own question.

Instead of overriding setOnTouchListener of the ListView I have made a custom ListView and Overridden the  onInterceptTouchEvent event inside the custom ListView.

Please see the code below :

```
public class CustomListView extends ListView {

    public CustomListView(Context context,
            List<DetailSummaryMonth> detailSummaryMonths) {
        super(context);
        init(context);

    }

    public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        if (getAdapter().getCount() > 3)

            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }

}
```